# Not able to connect to mongo atlas from Intellij Idea ultimate/ DataGrip

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, datagrip

I am not able to connect to mongo atlas from intellij idea/ DataGrip, connection test is passing,
[connection test success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQNF0.png)

after that when i click apply and okay, i am getting error saying  Driver class "com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException(no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)"[connection error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr3oP.png)

Comment: Please make sure to check with version from https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download/ If issue remains please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: Mongo version is not detected correctly. File an issue in [DataGrip YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE) and attach full IDE logs.


Additionally, could you specify your cloud provider and region? E.g. AWS, us-west-2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem, the mongo atlas url should be in this format to work
**mongodb+srv://cluster0-itndz.mongodb.net/BookDb**. Before i was trying with **mongodb://cluster0-itndz.mongodb.net/BookDb** without **+srv** which was passing the connection test in my Intellij ultimate/DataGrip and giving error i mentioned in the question when i click on apply.

Below is the working format image.

[Working connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4IsH.png)

Comment: yeah, basically, just copy/paste the url (from altas) to the URL in the setting, then it will parse the URL and fill in other corresponding field automatically.

Then just need fill the database manually